# Tensorflow 2.3 - 'Keyword argument not understood:', 'input'

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to use the functional API of Keras to model skip connections in a neural net that I intend to use for a segmentation task, and I got the aforementioned error -

Here's my code:

```
def unet_model(input_size = (256,256,1)):
    input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_size)
    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(input_)
    conv1 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv1)
    pool1 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool1)
    conv2 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv2)
    pool2 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool2)
    conv3 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv3)
    pool3 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv3)
    conv4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool3)
    conv4 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv4)
    drop4 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv4)
    pool4 = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(drop4)

    conv5 = keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(pool4)
    conv5 = keras.layers.Conv2D(1024, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv5)
    drop5 = keras.layers.Dropout(0.5)(conv5)

    up6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
    merge6 = keras.layers.Concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
    conv6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
    conv6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

    up7 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv6))
    merge7 = keras.layers.Concatenate([conv3,up7], axis = 3)
    conv7 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge7)
    conv7 = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv7)

    up8 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv7))
    merge8 = keras.layers.Concatenate([conv2,up8], axis = 3)
    conv8 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge8)
    conv8 = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv8)

    up9 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(conv8))
    merge9 = keras.layers.Concatenate([conv1,up9], axis = 3)
    conv9 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge9)
    conv9 = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv9 = keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv9)
    conv10 = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 1, activation = 'softmax')(conv9)

    model = keras.Model(inputs = [input_], outputs = [conv10])

    model.compile(optimizer = Adam(lr = 1e-4), loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

    return model
```

I get the error when I do:

```
from unet_model import unet_model
model = unet_model()
```

**What's wrong? The construction seems to be in accordance with the documentation. Please help me out!**

**UPDATE:**
I replaced **Concatenate** with **concatenate** after [reading this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584258/keras-concatenate-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-axis), and I have a different error now:

```
     24 
     25         up6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 2, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(keras.layers.UpSampling2D(size = (2,2))(drop5))
---> 26         merge6 = keras.layers.concatenate([drop4,up6], axis = 3)
     27         conv6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(merge6)
     28         conv6 = keras.layers.Conv2D(512, 3, activation = 'relu', padding = 'same', kernel_initializer = 'he_normal')(conv6)

TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'axis'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

** I am cloning this repository when I faced this similar issue.
https://github.com/zhixuhao/unet

I followed these solution to fixed this issue. [TypeError: ('Keyword argument not understood:', 'input')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63497874/typeerror-keyword-argument-not-understood-input)

Change:

```
input --> inputs 
output --> outputs
```

As for the concatenation,
[Keras Concatenate TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'axis'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584258/keras-concatenate-typeerror-init-got-multiple-values-for-argument-axis)

```
Concatenation --> concatenation
```